# streaming audio and video in python

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video

so I found this code somewhere and I tried running it:

```
import cv2
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer


video_path = "video.mp4"


def video_audio(path):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    player = MediaPlayer(video_path)
    while True:
        ret, frame = video.read()
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
        if not ret:
            print("End of video")
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
        if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
            # audio
            img, t = audio_frame
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


video_audio(video_path)
```

it does actually play the video and audio, but there is a delay between the two (current audio frame is played ahead of the current video frame)

does anyone know a possible solution to fix that?

Comment: try to use sounddevice library to play audio. Here you can find example of playing video with sound via cv2 and sounddevice: https://github.com/CrackAndDie/vitalas_py/tree/master

Comment: I'll take a look at that now. thank you very much! may I ask what project is it?

Comment: this project is smth like 'simple video editor'